# MVC: Just me or is IsValidField illogical

Tags: asp.net-mvc, logic

While I was writing some code to print out JS when a field is not valid in the `ModelState` is came to the following method:

`ModelState.IsValidField(string key)`

The comment in IntelliSense tells me:

> Returns true if there is any System.Web.Mvc.ModelError associated or prefixed with the specific key.

While I ask whether a field is valid it will return `false` in case it is not valid and `true` if it is valid.

This seems quite illogical, yet I haven't found any resource on the web that confirms this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did another simple test, and actually the method does behave as it should, the description in IntelliSense is just misleading.

Answer (score 0):

I think that is to say whether this field requires Validation not whether if it is valid.  though you have a point in that it seems to be misleading.   Might have to dig deeper for reasoning here or naming.